# Traceback error when I am attempting to grab all box scores

Tags: python, nba-api

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers  = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

from nba_api.stats.endpoints import leaguegamefinder

# get game logs from the reg season
gamefinder = leaguegamefinder.LeagueGameFinder(season_nullable='2020-21',
                                               league_id_nullable='00',
                                               season_type_nullable='Regular Season')
games = gamefinder.get_data_frames()[0]

# get a list of distinct game ids
game_id = games['GAME_ID'].unique().tolist()

player_stats_data = boxscoreadvancedv2.BoxScoreAdvancedV2(game_id=game_id, headers=headers, timeout=100)
stats_df = player_stats_data.get_data_frames()[0]
stats_df.head()
```

I get error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error.

I believe it has something to do with my game id's being in a list ? Because when I run a specfic game id number, so:

```
player_stats_data = boxscoreadvancedv2.BoxScoreAdvancedV2(game_id='000127338', headers=headers, timeout=100)
    stats_df = player_stats_data.get_data_frames()[0]
    stats_df.head()
```

It returns the data from that game.

Why is it not reading all game id's in the list though?

EDIT:

**Here is the for loop I have created after receiving an answer. This for loop has solved my issue. **

```
for game_id in game_ids:
    player_stats_data = boxscoreadvancedv2.BoxScoreAdvancedV2(game_id=game_id, headers=headers, timeout=100)
    time.sleep(.600)
    df = player_stats_data.player_stats.get_data_frame()
    df['GAME_ID'] = game_id
    print(game_id)
    boxscores.append(df)
```

Comment: Because the specification of the API says that it just takes a single game ID.

Comment: use a `for` loop to process all the games in the list.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up getting the for loop working. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [API documentation](https://github.com/swar/nba_api/blob/master/docs/nba_api/stats/endpoints/boxscoreadvancedv2.md), it takes a single game id.

One approach could be to loop over the game ids you have:

```py
game_ids = games['GAME_ID'].unique().tolist()
for game_id in game_ids:
    player_stats_data = boxscoreadvancedv2.BoxScoreAdvancedV2(game_id=game_id, headers=headers, timeout=100)
    # Use the stats...
```